# Ubuntu-16.04 - Hibernate5.2 - PostgreSql9.5 Password Authentication Issue

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, ubuntu

I am using PostgreSql for the first time and stuck with connection authentication problem. I have created a new user "hibernate" with password and able to make connection through Squirrel SQL client. However when I use the same username and password in Hibernate, it fails stating that authentication failed for my "desktop username" (Yes. somewhere my local user name gets in and I am not able to figure out.

Can someone tell me what could be wrong with my PostgreSQL configuration ?

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="connection.driver.class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="connection.name">hibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hibernate</property>
```

Error Details:

> Jul 16, 2016 10:31:44 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO:
>   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.1.Final} Jul 16, 2016 10:31:44 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found Jul 16, 2016 10:31:44 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist Jul 16, 2016 10:31:47 PM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} Jul 16, 2016 10:31:47 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) Jul 16, 2016 10:31:47 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [null] at URL
>   [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb] Jul 16, 2016 10:31:47
>   PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****,
>   name=hibernate, driver.class=org.postgresql.Driver} Jul 16, 2016
>   10:31:47 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false Jul 16, 2016
>   10:31:47 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections
>    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1) Jul
>   16, 2016 10:31:48 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   stop INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool
>   [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb] Jul 16, 2016 10:31:48
>   PM org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl
>   stopService INFO: HHH000369: Error stopping service [class
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl]
>   : java.lang.NullPointerException Error
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:179)
>     at com.sample.test.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:28) Caused
>   by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling
>   DriverManager#getConnection   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:37)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.(PooledConnections.java:40)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.(PooledConnections.java:19)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL:
>   password authentication failed for user "raja"    at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:433)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:215)   at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:406)     at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:274)    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:34)
>     ... 28 more

Comment: did you see this error message? are you sure you are using correct user? **at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254) ... 13 more Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "raja" at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:433)**

Comment: I have configured connection.name as "hibernate", the new user name I have created. Even the logs states the same 
**INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [null] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]
Jul 16, 2016 10:31:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, name=hibernate, driver.class=org.postgresql.Driver}**  But still for some reason it is using "raja", my the login name in ubuntu.